# Inheriting custom fields from top of hierarchy?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have an organization ABC under which user X is assigned. Custom fields are defined for the organization ABC. 
Is there a way in which i can get the custom field of ABC when accessing X ?
Is the custom field inherited through the hierarchy ?

PS: I'm accessing liferay using `jsonws'

Answer (score 1):

There's no inheritance for Custom Fields. They're typically attached to a single element, e.g. your Organization ABC.

Your question mixes Organization ABC and User X - a Custom Field would be *either* for a user, *or* for an organization. It'd be your task to traverse all of the organizations that a user is member of, and this traversal potentially includes the parents of those organizations.

Comment: Thanks Olay. Is that same for organization and sub-organization instead of organization and user hierarchy?

Comment: Yes. The very first sentence of my answer is absolute: *There is no inheritance for Custom Fields*.